# Why I cannot get a result value from T-SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to learn function in SQL Server, and I don't know why I cannot get a proper result from a T-SQL function.

The query what creates function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION yuri_func1 
     (@valDate VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @valWeekday VARCHAR(10);

    SET @valWeekday = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @valDate);

    RETURN @valWeekday;
END
```

And the other query is

```
select dbo.yuri_func1('2017-12-29') as [요일]
```

but the only result I got is just

> Blank. (="")

But when I executed function like this,

```
select DATENAME(WEEKDAY, '2017-12-29')
```

the result was

```
MONDAY
```

I still don't get that why they return different results.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: you have not defined the size of return type correct and define the size as `RETURNS VARCHAR(10)`

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, I really appreciate your comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you should be accepting DateTime as a parameter in your function and not varchar

```
create Function yuri_func1 (@valDate DateTime) --Wrong parameter type
RETURN VARCHAR(10) -- No proper sizing of return type
AS
BEGIN
    declare @valWeekday varCHAR(10);

    Set @valWeekday = DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@valDate);


    return @valWeekday;
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Alander. As you commented, I changed function query. and it worked! I appreciate that ;)